# Como consigo acessar o terminal de comandos do android

Tags: android

Como consigo acessar o terminal de comandos do android

Eu preciso executar comandos num android mas não tenho ideia como acesso o terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tentou instalar um app de terminal?
Por exemplo: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=pt

Comment: MAs é possivel fazer isso remotamente como eu faço com os servidores usando o shell?

Comment: Se entendi a pergunta, você pode instalar um app de servidor web, como o paw server (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver) ou uma solução similar.